# Object allocation during draw/layout?

Tags: java, android

I get 3 warning for object allocation during draw/layout

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setARGB(50,100,100,250);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setTextSize(50);
textPaint.setTypeface(font);
canvas.drawText("Logan is awesom",canvas.getWidth()/2,200,textPaint);
canvas.drawBitmap(pBall, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY, null);
if (changingY <canvas.getHeight()){
changingY += 10;
}else{
changingY=0;
}
Rect middleRect = new Rect();
middleRect.set(0, 400, canvas.getWidth(), 550);
Paint ourBlue = new Paint();
ourBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawRect(middleRect, ourBlue);
```

I get an error on new Rect(); 
and on both new Paint();

The exact error is avoid object allocation during draw/layout operations (prelocate and reuse instead)

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: The exact error is avoid object allocation during draw/layout operations (prelocate and reuse instead)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well, your 'error' points to exact problem. `onDraw()` method is called by OS many-many times, thus allocating something within this function is extremely bad idea.
You need to allocate your `Rect` and `Paint` beforehand and just use them within `onDraw`

```
class YourClass extends View
{
    Rect middleRect;
    Paint ourBlue;
    Paint textPaint;

    public YourClass()
    {
         //constructor
         init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        middleRect = new Rect();
        ourBlue; = new Paint();
        textPaint = new Paint();

        ourBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        textPaint.setARGB(50,100,100,250);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setTextSize(50);
        textPaint.setTypeface(font);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        canvas.drawText("Logan is awesom",canvas.getWidth()/2,200,textPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(pBall, (canvas.getWidth()/2), changingY, null);
        if (changingY <canvas.getHeight()){
            changingY += 10;
        }else{
            changingY=0;
        }

        //if canvas size doesn't change - this can be moved to init() as well
        middleRect.set(0, 400, canvas.getWidth(), 550);

        canvas.drawRect(middleRect, ourBlue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have got this error in layout especially when using display metrices.

I have used this imageview :

```
   <com.steve.thirdparty.ScalableImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_posted_img_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/golive_load_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_posted_msg_post_items_home"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"/>
```

**ScalableImageView.java:**

import static com.steve.TabHomeActivity.displaymetrics;

```
public class ScalableImageView extends ImageView {


        ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

}
```

I solved this issue by adding the static DisplayMetrices in onCreate() method in Activity.

**TabHomeActivity.java:**

```
public static DisplayMetrics displaymetrics;

*inside onCreate()*

 displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
```

Answer (score -4):

> avoid object allocation during draw/layout operations **(prelocate and reuse instead)**

The message give You a solution on plate, so I don't understand what is Your question.

You have to move creation of new objects to onCreate method, so they are created just once and use them later in onDraw method.